# Subscribe callback not called when empty Observable returned

Tags: javascript, rxjs, jasmine

I expect the `subscribe` callback to be called when returning an empty Observable, similar to `Promise.resolve([])`:

```
import { EMPTY } from 'rxjs';

function funcToTest(): Observable<any[]> {
  return EMPTY;
};

test('returns empty array', (done) => {
  funcToTest().subscribe(() => {
    done();
  });
});
```

Instead, it returns this error:

```
Error: Timeout - Async function did not complete within 5000ms (set by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observables act differently to promises. The RxJS `EMPTY` Observable doesn't call the 'success' callback, only the 'complete' callback. The `done` function should be called in 'complete' rather than in 'success':

```
funcToTest().subscribe({
  success()  { /* Called when 'x' is returned, e.g. after the subscriber calls 'next' */ },
  error(err) { /* Called on an error. */ },
  complete() {
    /* Called after the subscriber calls 'complete'. No more values can be returned */
    done();
  }
});
```

See the examples in the docs: https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/observable